# Enable migrations in class library project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

How to enable migrations in a class library project?

I'm building a project using **Code First EF5**. I want to separate the data and the mvc web project by adding a class library project.

Right now the migrations is enabled in the mvc web project. I'll have to remove that too.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to do it using the "Package Manager Console" (View > Other Windows > Package Manager Console).

Ensure the `default project` drop down is set to the class library project you want to enable migrations for, ensure you have a reference to the Entity Framework DLL in the project, and then run `enable-migrations`.

To run `update-database` commands etc you'll need an `app.config` file that includes a connection string for each of your data contexts.

Comment: Hi, i've also configured the simple membership profider in the webconfig to use my database. Do i have to move that from the webconfig to the appconfig of the class lib project? And what about removing the migrations in the web application which i have already enabled in that project?

Answer (score 0):

in many EF articles they mentioned Enable-Migrations command but no example with parameters simply specify project name where your db context and target web project or console program where config with connection string defined:

**Package manager console**
Enable-Migrations -ProjectName "MyApp.Data.Library" -StartUpProjectName "MyApp"